# Daily postgresql cron error log file

Tags: logging, cron, postgresql, sql

I am getting these emails daily:

/etc/cron.daily/logrotate:
error: error accessing /var/log/postgresql: No such file or directory
error: postgresql-common:1 glob failed for /var/log/postgresql/*.log

error: found error in /var/log/postgresql/*.log , skipping

I don't use postgresql database therefore guessing postgresql is not installed at all by default, wondered what is the most appropriate method for this, find a way to stop these messages or have postgresql installed? Although I don't believe I will be using it as I hardly know what it is. I use MySQL.

Server: Ubuntu 12.04.4 LTS

Any opinions on the method to take?

Answer (score 0):

Look in the folder `/etc/logrotate.d/`there are some file for the logrotation. I think there is a logrotate file for postgres. I think you can delete that file. Otherwise check the other files if you can find some other rules.